# Create an instance from volume in openstach with python-novaclient

Tags: python, openstack, novaclient, openstack-cinder

I am trying to create an instance from a bootable volume in openstack using python-novaclient.

The steps I am taking are following:

Step1: create a volume with an Image "Centos" with 100GB.
Step2: create an instance with the volume that I created in step1.

However, I must be doing something wrong or missing some information that it is not able to complete the task.

Here are my commands in python shell.

```
import time, getpass
from cinderclient import client
from novaclient.client import Client


project_name = 'project'
region_name = 'region'
keystone_link = 'https://keystone.net:5000/v2.0'
network_zone = "Public"
key_name = 'key_pair'

user = 'user'
pswd = getpass.getpass('Password: ')



# create a connection
cinder = client.Client('1', user, pswd, project_name, keystone_link, region_name = region_name)

# get the volume id that we will attach
print(cinder.volumes.list())
[<Volume: 1d36203e-b90d-458f-99db-8690148b9600>, <Volume: d734f5fc-87f2-41dd-887e-c586bf76d116>]

vol1 = cinder.volumes.list()[1]
vol1.id

block_device_mapping = {'device_name': vol1.id, 'mapping': '/dev/vda'}



### +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ###
# now create a connection with nova and create then instance object
nova = Client(2, user, pswd, project_name, keystone_link, region_name = region_name)

# find the image 
image = nova.images.find(name="NETO CentOS 6.4 x86_64 v2.2")

# get the flavor
flavor = nova.flavors.find(name="m1.large")

#get the network and attach
network = nova.networks.find(label=network_zone)
nics = [{'net-id': network.id}]

# get the keyname and attach
key_pair = nova.keypairs.get(key_name)

s1 = 'nova-vol-test'

server = nova.servers.create(name = s1, image = image.id, block_device_mapping = block_device_mapping, flavor = flavor.id, nics = nics, key_name = key_pair.name)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/novaclient/v1_1/servers.py", line 902, in create
    **boot_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/novaclient/v1_1/servers.py", line 554, in _boot
    return_raw=return_raw, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/novaclient/base.py", line 100, in _create
    _resp, body = self.api.client.post(url, body=body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/novaclient/client.py", line 490, in post
    return self._cs_request(url, 'POST', **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/novaclient/client.py", line 465, in _cs_request
    resp, body = self._time_request(url, method, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/novaclient/client.py", line 439, in _time_request
    resp, body = self.request(url, method, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/novaclient/client.py", line 433, in request
    raise exceptions.from_response(resp, body, url, method)
novaclient.exceptions.BadRequest: Block Device Mapping is Invalid: failed to get volume /dev/vda. (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-2b9db4e1-f24f-48c6-8660-822741ca52ad)
>>>
```

I tried to find any documentation so that I can solve this on my own, however, I was not able to.

If anyone has tried this before, I would appreciate there help on this.

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by using this dictionary:

```
block_dev_mapping = {'vda':'uuid of the volume you want to use'}
```

I then called it in the create method like this:

```
instance = nova.servers.create(name="python-test3", image='', block_device_mapping=block_dev_mapping,
                                    flavor=flavor, key_name="my-keypair", nics=nics)
```

Comment: I did try this block_dev_mapping = {'vda':'uuid of the volume you want to use'} among other variations, however, none of them seemed to work. Surprisingly it works now. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @MurtazaPitalwala So, do we know why it surprisingly works now?